# Docker Compose Up works locally, fails to deploy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy my docker container (hosting two images in a container) to AWS. I can succesfully run my `docker compose up` locally, and that builds and runs the container on my local Docker.

However, when I have set up a new context for ECS, and switched to this new context. However, when I run `docker compose up` (which I believe should now deploy to AWS), I get the error `docker.io/xxxx/concordejs_backend:latest: not found`.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: xxxx/concordejs_backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: concorde-backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  frontend:
    image: xxxx/concordejs_frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: concorde-frontend
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
```

Comment: Are these images published on dockerhub? Is it private?

Comment: You should be using either `image` or `build` in a compose file, not both.

Comment: @m90 no, it's possible to use both. If you have two it tags image after building it. Convenient in some cases.

Comment: @anemyte is this a new feature? I remember seeing errors about using both accidentally.

Comment: @m90 Don't know when it was added but I certainly used it about a year ago with `docker-compose`. Or were your speaking about errors in AWS ECS? I'm not sure if this thing would ignore this or complain.

Comment: @anemyte I would expect ECS to behave like docker-compose itself, but I don't know. Thanks for sharing this, it could definitely be handy at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image has been built on your local machine and is subquently retrieved from their each time you launch docker-compose locally.

The AWS service is trying to retrieve the image from the public repository docker.io (dockerhub) since it doesn't have the image you built locally.

One solution might be to push your local image to dockerhub for it to be accessible by ECS or you can use AWS's repository service, ECR. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_on_ECS.html